# Sed add text after matched patterns

Tags: sed

I've a pattern of

```
62G   57G  52%
```

I want to have them in separate lines and
After the first matched G Free
After the second Used
After the third Utilised

So it should looks like this

```
62G Free 
57G Used  
52% Utilised
```

Comment: *if* this is `df` output and you're on Linux, consider using the `--output` option.

Comment: It hurts my brain that 57 is not 52% of 62; I hope that's not your actual data (or interpretation of it)

Comment: @Jeff Lol no dear, it's SDCARD with 128GB size,  this is the actual code yes by df - h         df -h  | grep 179B > /storage/565F-179B/t && sed 's/\/dev\/block\/vold\/public:179,1 //g' /storage/565F-179B/t > /storage/565F-179B/t1 && sed  's/\/mnt.*//' /storage/565F-179B/t1 > /storage/565F-179B/t2
sed 's/119G//g'  /storage/565F-179B/t2 > /storage/565F-179B/t3
awk '{ printf("%s Free\n%s Used\n%s Utilised\n", $1, $2, $3) }'  /storage/565F-179B/t3 >  /storage/565F-179B/t4
rm /storage/565F-179B/t
rm /storage/565F-179B/t1
rm /storage/565F-179B/t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is located in a file called `file`, the following command would read each line of that file and output its three columns on the format that you prescribe:

```
$ awk '{ printf("%s Free\n%s Used\n%s Utilised\n", $1, $2, $3) }' file
62G Free
57G Used
52% Utilised
```

For each line of input, the block in the code will be executed.  That block contains a single `printf()` statement that formats the three whitespace-delimited columns into three lines with added text.

Doing this with `sed` would not be impossible, but unnecessarily difficult:

```
$ sed -e 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/:/g' -e 's/:/ Free@/' -e 's/:/ Used@/' -e 's/%/% Utilised/' -e 'y/@/\n/' file
62G Free
57G Used
52% Utilised
```

This would first compress all whitespace characters into single `:` characters, then insert the wanted added text strings by replacing these `:` characters, one by one.  While inserting, we also add `@` characters wherever we want to later insert a newline. As tho last step we change all the inserted `@` characters to newlines.

Note that with GNU `sed`, which allows using `\n` in the replacement part of the `s///` command, you could make it shorter:

```
$ gsed -E -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/:/g' -e 's/:/ Free\n/' -e 's/:/ Used\n/' -e 's/%/% Utilised/' file
62G Free
57G Used
52% Utilised
```

Both of these `sed` solutions relies on the fact that we can use `:` and `@` as temporary "placeholder characters" in the string and that these don't occur elsewhere in it.